# How to use dynamic attributes / columns in Squeel statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, squeel

In my [previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604949/how-to-dynamically-generate-association-names) I ended up that the following code seems to work as expected:

```
def my_squeel_query
  table_name = Squeel::Nodes::Stub.new("#{self.class.to_s.tableize}_comment_associations".to_sym)

  commenters.
    .where{
      table_name.article_id.eq(my{self.id})
    }
end
```

**Is it possible to make the `article_id` statement as dynamic as made for the `table_name` variable?**

That is, I would like to make something as-like the following:

```
def my_squeel_query
  table_name = Squeel::Nodes::Stub.new("#{self.class.to_s.tableize}_comment_associations".to_sym)

  commenters.
    .where{
      table_name.<DYNAMIC_KEY>.eq(my{self.id}) # '<DYNAMIC_KEY>' refers to a column name present in the 'commenters' database table.
    }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send).

```
column_name = :article_id
commenters.where{
  table_name.send(column_name).eq(my{self.id})
}
```

Comment: How to set the `_column_name_` value?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. I edited my answer but column_name can be a symbol or a string. Just set the columns you want to check for somewhere and that is it.

Comment: ...and just replace `table_name` with you table name.

Comment: Better yet, you can use `__send__`, to avoid having to type the table name: `commenters.where{__send__(column_name).eq(my{self.id})}`